# Problema con ScrollReveal con tabs de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con la librería ScrollReveal al cargar una animación dentro de tabs de bootstrap (uso bootstrap 5).
En la primer tab funciona bien pero en las demás no. Pareciera como si no reconociese el scroll porque quedan los elementos escondidos por la librería pero nunca los muestra.

Lo curioso es que cuando abro el inspector del explorador empieza a funcionar en esa tab y deja de funcionar en las demás.

Ya probé intentando recargar el javascript cuando cambio de tab pero no cambia nada.

Repliqué esto mismo en codepen para que lo puedan ver:

```js
//  window.sr = ScrollReveal()
    ScrollReveal({
      reset: true
    });
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.reveal_left', {
      delay: 800,
      origin: 'left',
      distance: '-500px'
    })
```

```css
.square{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}
h4{
  color:blue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h4>Al final de cada tab se encuentra el objeto square con la animacion de ScrollReveal: </h4>
<div class="d-flex align-items-start">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-messages" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-settings" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
      <h1>Home Section </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit blandit ac augue venenatis semper, quisque urna lobortis nisl hac. Senectus dapibus faucibus aliquam sodales dignissim dui vestibulum curae in proin, lectus nam magna eget inceptos malesuada lacinia tempus tristique, eu iaculis neque at quisque platea fringilla duis erat. Et turpis arcu duis conubia leo auctor purus, himenaeos class mus sollicitudin ante praesent, scelerisque mollis egestas feugiat massa aptent. Cursus curae aliquet penatibus magna et lobortis metus augue, faucibus posuere nisi donec malesuada nam neque.

Orci risus scelerisque pulvinar mauris turpis a, suspendisse dui hendrerit phasellus conubia est velit, dictumst praesent nisl vivamus ultricies. Primis ornare fringilla natoque montes erat netus litora viverra mi, turpis nostra purus malesuada odio porttitor cum hendrerit suspendisse praesent, risus pharetra tellus ridiculus in nec cubilia fames. Habitant non mauris etiam libero iaculis aptent ultricies nullam, vulputate nisi bibendum egestas tincidunt scelerisque integer.</p>
      <div class="reveal_left square">
        square with revela class
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
            <h1>Profile </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit blandit ac augue venenatis semper, quisque urna lobortis nisl hac. Senectus dapibus faucibus aliquam sodales dignissim dui vestibulum curae in proin, lectus nam magna eget inceptos malesuada lacinia tempus tristique, eu iaculis neque at quisque platea fringilla duis erat. Et turpis arcu duis conubia leo auctor purus, himenaeos class mus sollicitudin ante praesent, scelerisque mollis egestas feugiat massa aptent. Cursus curae aliquet penatibus magna et lobortis metus augue, faucibus posuere nisi donec malesuada nam neque.

Orci risus scelerisque pulvinar mauris turpis a, suspendisse dui hendrerit phasellus conubia est velit, dictumst praesent nisl vivamus ultricies. Primis ornare fringilla natoque montes erat netus litora viverra mi, turpis nostra purus malesuada odio porttitor cum hendrerit suspendisse praesent, risus pharetra tellus ridiculus in nec cubilia fames. Habitant non mauris etiam libero iaculis aptent ultricies nullam, vulputate nisi bibendum egestas tincidunt scelerisque integer.</p>
          <div class="reveal_left square">
        square with revela class
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
            <h1>Messages</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit blandit ac augue venenatis semper, quisque urna lobortis nisl hac. Senectus dapibus faucibus aliquam sodales dignissim dui vestibulum curae in proin, lectus nam magna eget inceptos malesuada lacinia tempus tristique, eu iaculis neque at quisque platea fringilla duis erat. Et turpis arcu duis conubia leo auctor purus, himenaeos class mus sollicitudin ante praesent, scelerisque mollis egestas feugiat massa aptent. Cursus curae aliquet penatibus magna et lobortis metus augue, faucibus posuere nisi donec malesuada nam neque.

Orci risus scelerisque pulvinar mauris turpis a, suspendisse dui hendrerit phasellus conubia est velit, dictumst praesent nisl vivamus ultricies. Primis ornare fringilla natoque montes erat netus litora viverra mi, turpis nostra purus malesuada odio porttitor cum hendrerit suspendisse praesent, risus pharetra tellus ridiculus in nec cubilia fames. Habitant non mauris etiam libero iaculis aptent ultricies nullam, vulputate nisi bibendum egestas tincidunt scelerisque integer.</p>
              <div class="reveal_left square">
        square with revela class
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
            <h1>Settings</h1>
              <div class="reveal_left square">
        square with revela class
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Mi codigo completo](https://codepen.io/gonzalo-lorenzo-eijo/pen/XWBjXwZ)
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Como quieres que te ayudemos si no sabemos nada de tu proyecto ni tu codigo?

Comment: Gracias Daniel. Acabo de añadir un enlace de codepen para ilustrar el problema.

Comment: es mejor pegar  el código en la pregunta porque es posible que el enlace se caiga o modifiques el código y ya no se puede ver el problema.

Comment: Gonzalo creo que tu problema es que no incluyes la apis de scrollReveal: <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

Comment: En el codepen yo veo la librería incluida, @DanielBriceño. Puedes verla tú mismo si accedes a la pestaña "Settings" del proyecto que ha pasado, en el apartado de "JS", están tanto los import del JS de bootstrap como ScrollReveal.

Comment: @Benito-B Huy, no sabia que codes-pen trae esa opción